# How can I execute mysql query from command line on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySql on Server 2008 R2 a while back. I am trying to run some queries from the command lines and I am instructed by some tutorials on the web. I am not sure How can I run commands from cmd?

Do I need to install additional futures for me to be able to run queries from the command line? and how?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `mysql` command-line tool will get you there, where you may need to provide any credentials to get access. This comes with most installations of MySQL, but you'll need to check that it's located in your `PATH` or it might not be found.

It may be easier to use the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) tool to connect and run queries instead.